# Merge multiple objects in an array into one based one key value pair using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dynamically generated array based on the grid filtered values like below

```
    [
        {
            attributeId: 145,
            attributeName: "Status",
            filterOperator: "Is equal to",
            filterValue: "Active",
            SortBy: ""
        },
        {
            attributeId: 161,
            attributeName: "Code",
            filterOperator: "Contains",
            filterValue: "22",
            SortBy: ""
        },
        {
            attributeId: 161,
            attributeName: "Code",
            filterOperator: "",
            filterValue: "",
            SortBy: "ASC"
        }
    ]
```

Here two objects are generated with same 'attributeId' but one object has SortBy details and another has filtering details. Now I wanted to merge those two objects into one so that it will become like

```
    {
            attributeId: 161,
            attributeName: "Code",
            filterOperator: "Contains",
            filterValue: "22",
            SortBy: "ASC"
    }
```

If the objects are idetical, I can able to remove the duplicates using

```
this.columnList = Object.values(this.columnList.reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, {
  [cur.attributeName]: cur
}), {}));
```

Here this.columnList is the array name. Any suggestions here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could `reduce` the array and group it based on `attributeId`. If the `attributeId` already exists in the accumulator, Loop through the entries of the object and update each value if it is not empty. If the `attributeId` doesn't exist, add it to the accumulator

```js
const input=[{attributeId:145,attributeName:"Status",filterOperator:"Is equal to",filterValue:"Active",SortBy:""},{attributeId:161,attributeName:"Code",filterOperator:"Contains",filterValue:"22",SortBy:""},{attributeId:161,attributeName:"Code",filterOperator:"",filterValue:"",SortBy:"ASC"}];

const merged = input.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const { attributeId, ...rest } = o;
  
  if (!acc[attributeId]) 
    acc[attributeId] = { ...o }
  else 
  {
    Object.entries(rest).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (v)
        acc[attributeId][k] = v
    })
  }
  
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

Comment: Hi adiga, can we convert this as a method having columnList array as parameter to use it in multiple places?

Comment: @vamsi sure. Just wrap it in a function and return the array

Answer (score 0):

We can reduce above code to this:

```js
var data = [ { attributeId: 145, attributeName: "Status", filterOperator: "Is equal to", filterValue: "Active", SortBy: "" }, { attributeId: 161, attributeName: "Code", filterOperator: "", filterValue: "22", SortBy: "" }, { attributeId: 161, attributeName: "New Code", filterOperator: "Contains", filterValue: "", SortBy: "ASC" } ];

let getResolvedData = (array) => {
  return Object.values(array.reduce((acc, {attributeId, ...rest})=>{
   acc[attributeId] = acc[attributeId] || {attributeId};
   Object.entries(rest).forEach(([key,value])=>{
      if(acc[attributeId][key] && value) acc[attributeId][key] = value
      if(!acc[attributeId][key]) acc[attributeId][key] = value;
   })
   return acc;
},{}));
}

console.log(getResolvedData(data));
```

Comment: Can we make it as a method ?

Comment: attributeId is missing from the result??

Comment: Hi, if value is already present, then how to update it with new value? for now it is ignoring if value is present.

Comment: @vamsi do you have to update the existing value with the next iteration if present? Is this something you want ?

Comment: exactly that is what I need gorak!

Comment: @vamsi See edit. Let me know if this is what u need.

Comment: Gorak, if we pass null value to this method, it is keeping it's old value.. What change do I need to make it allow null value as well? For example, If status dropdown changed from 'inactive' to 'all', I need to pass 'null' when selected 'all', but it is keeping inactive only..